# How to get Selected Date on Infragistics WebMonthCalendar Control on client side

Tags: asp.net, infragistics

I'm using Infragistics for the first time. When I set selection mode to multi and i want to concatenate the selected dates in hidden field , for which i use client side event handle

```
function WebMonthCalendar1_SelectionChanged(sender, eventArgs)
{
    ///<summary>
    ///
    ///</summary>
    ///<param name="sender" type="Infragistics.Web.UI.WebMonthCalendar"></param>
    ///<param name="eventArgs" type="Infragistics.Web.UI.CalendarSelectionChangedEventArgs"></param>
    var days = sender.get_selectedDate;

    alert(sender);
    //Add code to handle your event here.
}
```

but this will return function definition like text, not selected date. Please kindly help me how can i select particular date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an expert in javascript, but the call should be

```
var days = sender.get_selectedDate();
```

Note the parenthesis at the end.